# moving maven .m2 folder

Tags: eclipse, windows, maven

in my Windows 7 i have a folder for maven in **C:Users/MyUser/.m2** , i need to move this folder to the E drive , i changed the **settings.xml** file to

```
<localRepository>E:/Maven/MavenRepo</localRepository>
```

,in **Eclipse** i changed the user's settings for maven to point to the **settings.xml** file but still downloading the artifacts in the same old folder on the C drive, How i can move that folder?

Comment: Windows > Preferences > Maven > User Settings > Local Repository (From merged user and global settings): what's the value in this field?

Comment: @A.DiMatteo this value is : C:\Users\MyUser\.m2\settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify which settings file you changed, the one in c:Users/MyUser/.m2 or the global settings file in maven-installation/conf folder.

Comment: i changed this file `c:Users/MyUser/.m2 `

Comment: you can probably first change the location of your settings.xml and move to E:/Maven/MavenRepo by using this command mvn -s E:/Maven/MavenRepo/settings.xml. Then delete the older .m2 folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can create link for a folder, for example **junction**, like

```
mklink /J .m2 new_location_path
```

or try to create 'soft link'

Answer (score -1):

I think cannot delete .m2 folder,execute maven command need it.